# Instantiate an array in C# - converted from VB

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am going to convert some legacy VB codes to C#.

The original code is `Me.variable1 = New Integer() {}`.

I used some converting website and get the answer as `this.variable1 == new int[]`.
However, the IDE gives error "Wrong number of indices inside []; expected 1".
It seems I have to declare the size of array.

What size of the array the VB codes gives us? is it size 1 or no size?

Thanks!

Comment: [Arrays Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: What happens to `Me.variable1` afterwards? Are you changing the number of array members? The VB statement creates an empty array. Are elements added later? If so, consider using `System.Collections.ArrayList` or any other suitable collection.

Comment: Note that the dupe link was item #1 on the list of "about" 1,030,000 google hits for "c#  Instantiate array" (searching just  SO).

Answer (score 2):

`this.variable1 = new int[]{}` should work. It just creates an empty array.

Unlucky is correct, you won't be able to add anything to this array, but if you get your array from something else (maybe for instance a service or another call), you can assign that array to this array.

Here is a working example.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/1xY2XV

Comment: @ the upvoter,  care to specify how this buggy answer is useful. `It just creates an empty array` how it is possible with `==`

Comment: Edited it. Thanks @un-lucky!

Answer (score 1):

`==` is used here as comparison operator, not assignment operator. you have to use `=` for assignment. You have to specify the size of the array or else you have to initialize its elements. So you should use like this :

```
this.variable1 = new int[10];
```

Or like this :

```
this.variable1 = new int[] { 10, 12, 15, 3, 2, 4, 19 };
```

This (`int[] variable1 = new int[] { };`) is valid declaration of an empty array, but you can't assign anything to this array.

Comment: Thanks! Since the VB coding creates an empty array, can we add element to this empty array created by VB codes?